Relocated Subpackages in PySNMP
I inherited some code that used PySNMP version 4.4.12, and while not very familiar with SNMP, it is my job to get some scripts working with the latest version of PySNMP. One issue I have is there was a function or class named MibVariable in pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner.cmdgen and it has been either relocated or deprecated in recent versions.  I found cmdgen was moved to the hlapi subpackage, but I can't find a replacement for what was called MibVariable. What should I do? I am using Python 3.10.

try from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdgen

pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.cmdgen is missing UsmUserData, UdpTransportTarget, MibVariable, usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol, and usmAesCfb128Protocol.

The oneliner related bits have been completely removed. So, you have to rewrite the related part with the remaining PySNMP API surface.
